# how to disable line wraparound in Microsoft Word 2010 outline view

Tags: ms-word, outline, unwrap

In outline view, the lines begin wrapping around if they're more than about 50 characters or so.

How can this wraparound be disabled?

Comment: Works now with word 2013 -- http://www.ehow.com/how_8503962_turn-word-wrap-ms-word.html

Comment: Word 2013 link does not state how to avoid text wrapping for text which is NOT situated around images

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Options, Advanced

Look in the panel entitled "Show document content"

There is a checkbox called "show text wrapped within the document window"

check it.

That should do the trick.

(how on earth one is supposed to figure that out for oneself I have no idea)

Comment: Thank you! This would have been super hard to find!

Comment: I also found this:  File > Options > Advanced > Show document content > Show text wrapped within the document window

Comment: 5 years later... Wow, 31000 views.  And I'm one of them.

Comment: This works great (and is much appreciated!) for on-screen viewing but it still wraps when I print